# Keep script execution in newly opened page

Tags: javascript

My script opens a page that I do not own and passes a parameter, which I want  to show in one of the input boxes of this newly open page.

I am happy if this works as a Chrome snippet, so I can try to make it a Chrome extension in the future.

// I have edited the code:

```
var valueToPass = $('font[color="green"]').first().text();
$('#div1').after("<button type='button' onclick='shortcut(valueToPass)'>Button</button>");


function shortcut(a){
 var newWin = window.open('http://newWin.com' , '_blank'); window.setTimeout('newWin.window.document.getElementById("theId").value = a;',1000)};
```

Now i get "Uncaught ReferenceError newWin is not defined" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open you new window like below,

```
var newWin = window.open('www.aaa.com?someVal='+'myVal' , '_blank');
```

now to add the value to the text box in the new window, set as below,

```
newWin.window.document.getElementById("textBoxId").value = myVal;
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil, please check the code again as I have revised it.

Comment: This is a very bad idea, as it is trivially susceptible to [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.